# Exception handling for netmiko in Python(bad ip address)

Tags: python-3.x, router, paramiko, cisco, netmiko

I am trying to give an exception for a program I am making to log into a Cisco switch and clear Port sec using Python and the Netmiko library. I would like to prompt the user for the IP address, so I would like to be able to let them know the IP address is bad(the user is not familiar with logging into cisco switches and using commands.)
I see two exceptions and have tried to create one exception rule for both, and also tried one for each. Here is the exception that comes when the IP of a switch is bad(does not exist).
*> Traceback (most recent call last):

Output

> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1046, in establish_connection
> self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
> to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 203, in _families_and_addresses
> addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Documents\GitHub\python\Practice OOP\practicce.py", line 18, in <module>
> net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_881)
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 365, in ConnectHandler
> return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 439, in **init**
> self._open()
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 444, in _open
> self.establish_connection()
> File "C:\Users\jesse.garcia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1068, in establish_connection
> raise NetmikoTimeoutException(msg)
> netmiko.exceptions.NetmikoTimeoutException: TCP connection to device failed.
>
> Common causes of this problem are:
> Incorrect hostname or IP address.
> Wrong TCP port.
> Intermediate firewall blocking access.
>
> Device settings: cisco_ios +95:22*

Here is what I have for code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import netmiko
import paramiko
import socket

ipadd = input("Please enter the IP address of the switch ")
port = input("Please enter the port ")
cisco_881 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host':   ipadd,
    'username': '',
    'password': '',
    'port' : 22,          # optional, defaults to 22
    'secret': '',     # optional, defaults to ''
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_881)
    

    try:
        net_connect.send_command(f'clear port-security sticky int g1/0/{port}')
    except (socket.gaierror, netmiko.exceptions.NetmikoTimeoutException):
        print("Ip address is bad. ")
```

I would like to handle the excetion with a message of ours so that when I deploy, it will be in a while loop and show the exception message, then prompt for the IP again.

I have also tried to use this piece of code to see what exactly the interpreter is seeing.

```
except Exception as err:
    exception_type = type(err).__name__
    print(exception_type)
```

as well as:

```
try:
    # Some stuff
except ConnectionRefusedError as err:
    print(f"Connection Refused: {err}")
except TimeoutError as err:
    print(f"Connection Refused: {err}")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Oops! {err}")
```

So far nothing seems to work. I just keep getting the output shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
from netmiko import ConnectHandler


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip_add = input("Please enter the IP address of the switch:-")
    port = input("Please enter the port:-")
    cisco_881 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host':   ip_add,
    'username': '',
    'password': '',
    'port' : 22,          # optional, defaults to 22
    'secret': '',     # optional, defaults to ''
    }
    result = {}
    command = f'clear port-security sticky int g1/0/{port}'
    try:
        with ConnectHandler(**cisco_881) as ssh:
            print('enabling wait...')
            ssh.enable()
            output = ssh.send_command(command)
            result[command] = output
    except Exception:
        print("Ip address is bad.")
    pprint(result, width=120)
```

For more info refer to documentation:-
https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/18_ssh_telnet/netmiko.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you @Shrimandhar . This worked perfectly. I did not know I needed the 'with' for it to work. I am researching it now to see why. Thanks again